# Angular: How can I alter a return inside a subscribe?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, observable

I have multiple components that leverage a function. They expect array of objects to be returned. However, there's one instance where I need to check the return value from an observable to alter the contents of the array before returning:

```
let projectMenu: MenuElement[];
...
this.myService.enabledFeatures.subscribe(features => {
  if (features[FeatureKeys.SPECIAL_KEY]) {
    projectMenu.push(this.getNewMenuItem(project));
    projectMenu.push(this.getSecondaryMenuItem(project));
  }
});

return projectMenu;
```

Obviously `return projectMenu` is going to return its current value before the subscribe does its magic. I basically need to turn that `subscribe` into a sync request. Maybe through an asyn await? Not quite sure how to go about this though.

Comment: Why not return the observable instead of the projectMenu (shifting responsability to the caller to subscribe) ? And as @Bitman suggested, use .pipe(map()) to transform/adjust emitted values.

Comment: @VincentAUDIBERT without getting to verbose, the use of this runs very deep in the application. Switching to an observable would require a refactor we don't have time to do. the map solution worked and was selected as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to change values before emiting:

```
  this.myService.enabledFeatures.pipe(
    map((features) => {
      let projectMenu: MenuElement[] = [];
      if (features[FeatureKeys.SPECIAL_KEY]) {
        projectMenu.push(this.getNewMenuItem(project));
        projectMenu.push(this.getSecondaryMenuItem(project));
      }
      return projectMenu;
    })
  ).subscribe()
```